# I want to split JSON value into two value

Tags: javascript, json, split

my JSON DATA is below

```
{
"response_code": 200,
"train": [
    "19005 (SAURASHTRA MAIL)",
    "19066 (BGKT BDTS EXP)"
],
"total": 2 }
```

other format is below of same data

```
{
"response_code": 200,
"train": [
    "(SAURASHTRA MAIL) (19005)",
    "(BGKT BDTS EXP) (19066)"
],
"total": 2  }
```

from both the above format i want to split **19005** & **SAURASHTRA MAIL** and popup alert msg for both the value.

how to split this? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str1 = "19005 (SAURASHTRA MAIL)";
var train_name1= str1.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1];
var train_number1 = str1.match(/\d+/g);

var str2 = "(SAURASHTRA MAIL) (19005)";
var train_name2= str2.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1];
var train_number2 = str2.match(/\d+/g);


alert("TRAIN NAME 1 : "+train_name2 +" AND TRAIN NUMBER : "+ train_number2 +", TRAIN NAME 2 : "+train_name2 +" AND TRAIN NUMBER : "+ train_number2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression and perform a match in a cascade. The result is an array with the whole result and the splitted values.

```js
var train = [
    "19005 (SAURASHTRA MAIL)",
    "19066 (BGKT BDTS EXP)",
    "(SAURASHTRA MAIL) (19005)",
    "(BGKT BDTS EXP) (19066)"
];

train.forEach(function (a) {
    var m = a.match(/\((.*)\) \((.*)\)/);
    if (m) {
        console.log('1number: ' + m[2]);
        console.log('1string: ' + m[1]);
        return;
    }
    m = a.match(/(.*) \((.*)\)/);
    if (m) {
        console.log('2number: ' + m[1]);
        console.log('2string: ' + m[2]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Loop over the trains array

Comment: `19005 (SAURASHTRA MAIL)` I think OP wants to get all the values in `trains` array split to give the 2 useful pieces. He would not know beforehand the values he needs to find.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this regex, it seems does what you wanted

https://regex101.com/r/cD0uC8/1

```
\"\((.*)?\)\s*\((\d*)\)\"|\"(\d*)\s*\((.*)?\)\"/g
```

'/g' is a modifier to applies the regex to all the lines